# How to change font size of chart title in downloaded pdf with jspdf

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, jspdf

I am using jspdf here.I am using Highchart plugin also
When you click submit1 button charts will generate,and when you press download button those chart will be downloaded as pdf.
Everything is working but I need to just reduce the font size of the chart title in downloaded pdf. http://plnkr.co/edit/Z3hJcC8pgzZxXPLWpfBw?p=preview
Here is my live demo in plunker. also here I have the html and javascript code

### HTML

```
<div><img id="logo" style="width:30%" src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/3.png"/>dddddddd</div>
 <input type="button" id="download"  value="download" /> click to console
  <div><button id="button1" class="button1">submit1</button></div>
  <p id="bottom-content">footer</p>
```

### SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var index = 0;
    var id = [];
    $('#button1').on('click', function() {
        $('body').append($("<div id='chart" + index + "'></div>"));

        Highcharts.chart('chart' + index, {
           title: {
        text: 'Chart-'+index+''
    },
            series: [{
                data: [1, 2, 3]
            }]
        });
        var temp = "chart" + index + "";
        console.log(temp);
        id.push(temp);

        index++;
    });

    $('#download').on('click', function() {
console.log(id);
  var doc = new jsPDF('portrait', 'pt', 'a4', true);
  var elementHandler = {
    '#ignorePDF': function(element, renderer) {
      return true;
    }
  };

  var source = document.getElementById("logo");
  doc.fromHTML(source, 15, 15, {
    'width': 200,
    'elementHandlers': elementHandler
  });

  var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
   var elements = id;

 // console.log(xx);
  for (let i in elements) {


      let svg = document.querySelectorAll('svg');
      let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      let canvasIE = document.createElement('canvas');
      let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      let data1 = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(svg[i]);

      canvg(canvas, data1);
      let svgBlob = new Blob([data1], {
        type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
      });

      let url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

      let img = new Image();
      img.src = url;
      img.onload = function() {
        context.canvas.width = $("#"+elements[i]).find('svg').width();
        context.canvas.height = $("#"+elements[i]).find('svg').height();

        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        // freeing up the memory as image is drawn to canvas
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

        var dataUrl;
        if (isIEBrowser()) { // Check of IE browser 
          var svg = $(elements[i]).highcharts().container.innerHTML;
          canvg(canvasIE, svg[i]);
          dataUrl = canvasIE.toDataURL('image/JPEG');
        } else {
          dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        }

        doc.addImage(dataUrl, 'JPEG', 20, 150, 560, 350);

          let bottomContent = document.getElementById("bottom-content");
  doc.fromHTML(bottomContent, 15, 700, {
    'width': 560,
    'elementHandlers': elementHandler
  });

  let logo = document.getElementById("logo");
         doc.fromHTML(logo, 15, 200, {
    'width': 560,
    'elementHandlers': elementHandler
  });

  doc.addPage();

      };



    }


  setTimeout(function() {
    doc.save('TestChart"'+index+'".pdf');
  }, 1000);

});
});
function isIEBrowser() {
  var ieBrowser;
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

  if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // Internet Explorer
  {
    ieBrowser = true;
  } else //Other browser
  {
    console.log('Other Browser');
    ieBrowser = false;
  }

  return ieBrowser;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `font-size` title style, after click on `download` button, in `setTitle` method:

```
var charts = Highcharts.charts;

charts.forEach(function(chart){
  chart.setTitle({
    style: {
      fontSize: '32px'
    }
  });
});
```

Live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/DpFULmbOa8vjk1VEZ5nD?p=preview

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#setTitle